# Batch shorter path QGIS (Snow map)

Tags: qgis, network-analyst, nearest-neighbor

I'm working on the famous John Snow map about cholera in Soho, London with QGIS

[image: John Snow map]

I use the data from  [Don Boyes](http://donboyes.com/2011/10/14/john-snow-and-serendipity/) and I extracted the street network from OpenStreetMap.

I have :

- a layer of pumps
- a layer of deaths
- a street layer

I have created a layer of Voronoi polygons.

[image: Pumps voronoi polygons map]

[The R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cholera/index.html) published by Peter Li show a network analysis bases on walking.

Is this possible with QGIS ?

[R package documentation : cholera: amend, augment and aid analysis of Snow’s cholera map](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cholera/readme/README.html)

[image: Pump neighborhood article map]

Comment: Play a shortest path (layer to point) for each pump (you can batch the algorithm), assemble the results and for a "deaths" ID, keep the shortest.